# Не подключается к серверу сокета

Tags: vue.js, canvas, socket.io

Пишу доску рисования (canvas) в реальном времени(socket)! На одном ноуте если войти от имени нескольких пользователей в одно время, чтобы проверить доску, то доска работает нормально. А если я захожу через другой ноут, который подключен к тому же wi-fi, то другой ноут не может подключиться к серверу. Выводится ошибка ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Можете подсказать что я делаю не так?

Код сервера:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const socketIO = require('socket.io')
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = socketIO(http, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
    },
  })

const port = 3000

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`${socket.id} has connectd`)

    socket.on('openRoom', (room) => {
      socket.join(room)

      socket.on('draw', (data) => {
          socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('data', { x: data.x, y: data.y, strokeWidth: data.strokeWidth, strokeColor: data.strokeColor })
      })
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', (socket) => console.log(`${socket.id} has disconnected`))
})

http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server has been started on port ${port}`)
})
```

кусок кода клиента внутри :

```
created () {
    this.socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connected', this.socket)
      this.socket.emit('openRoom', roomNumb)
    })
  },
methods: {
    mousedown (e) {
      this.isDrawing = true
      const rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
      const x = e.clientX - rect.left
      const y = e.clientY - rect.top
      this.startX = x
      this.startY = y
      this.context.beginPath()
      this.context.moveTo(this.startX, this.startY)
    },
    mousemove (e) {
      const rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
      const x = e.clientX - rect.left
      const y = e.clientY - rect.top
      const strokeWidth = this.currentWidth
      const strokeColor = this.colorArray[this.currentColor]
      if (this.isDrawing) {
        this.socket.emit('draw', { x, y, strokeWidth, strokeColor })
        this.context.lineTo(x, y)
        this.context.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        // this.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'
        this.context.lineCap = 'round'
        this.context.strokeStyle = strokeColor
        this.context.stroke()
        this.startX = x
        this.startY = y
        this.points.push({
          x: x,
          y: y
        })
      }
    },
    mouseup (e) {
      this.allPoints.push(this.points)
      console.log(this.allPoints)
      this.isDrawing = false
      this.points = []
    },
    toGetPoints: function () {
      this.socket.on('data', ({ x, y, strokeWidth, strokeColor }) => {
        this.context.lineTo(x, y)
        this.context.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        this.context.lineCap = 'round'
        this.context.strokeStyle = strokeColor
        this.context.stroke()
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, действительно ли Вы это имели в виду.

Строка клиента:

```
    this.socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
```

Это означает, что клиент подключается к `localhost`, или, другими словами, что у Вас в коде написано "клиент и сервер должны быть на одном компьютере"!

Если Вы действительно именно так написали в клиенте - то это первое место на исправление.

Попробуйте поставить сервер на какой то компьютер, а потом узнать его адрес в локальной сети (например, в пределах wifi)

На Windows это делается командой `ipconfig`, на линукс - чем то вроде `ip a` или `ifconfig`

Предположим, Вы определили адрес компа, на котором запущен сервер, как `192.168.1.101`. Попробуйте именно этот адрес пропсиать в клиента, и тогда клиент должен нормально заработать с нескольких компьютеров.

Если это "не работает" - надо искать причину, скорее всего, причина - это файервол!

В общем, думаю, что начало - именно такое. Как только заработает в пределах локалки - можно будет выводить сервер в интернет, можете тогда написать еще один вопрос.

Comment: Благодарю! Да, все заработало!